# How to rename uploaded images with spaces and special characters?

Tags: php, file-upload

So here i will share mu clean string function and my upload image code. i need help in using the function to clean the file name before being uploaded if the image file has names for example "credi--  @% sdfdsf..####tcard.jpg" i wish to clean it before upload for which i have a clean string function

```
function cleanStr($string) {
   $string = str_replace(' ', '-', $string);
   $string = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $string);
   return preg_replace('/-+/', '-', $string); 
}
```

and here is my upload image code

```
if(isset($_POST['upload'])) {
    $countfiles = count($_FILES['files']['name']);
    $query = "INSERT INTO images (post_id,name,image) VALUES(?,?,?)";
    $statement = $db->prepare($query);
    for($i = 0; $i < $countfiles; $i++) {
        $filename = date('Y-m-d-his').'-'.$_FILES['files']['name'][$i];
        $target_file = 'uploads/documents/'.$filename;
        $file_extension = pathinfo(
            $target_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);              
        $file_extension = strtolower($file_extension);
        $valid_extension = array("png","jpeg","jpg");       
        if(in_array($file_extension, $valid_extension)) {
            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$i],$target_file)){ 
                $statement->execute(array($_GET['id'],$filename,$target_file));
            }
        }
    }
header('Location: result.php?id='.$_GET['id'].'&action=UPLOADED');
exit;
}
```

can someone help me out cleaning the image name before being uploaded?

thanks alot

Comment: Maybe better will be better generate new name for image? Something like this - `$filename = uniqid(rand(), true) . '.png;`

Comment: nothing seems to be working. if i change $filename to $filename = uniqid(rand(), true); then nothing gets uploaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot modify the filename **before** being uploaded when using PHP because of the fact that PHP runs on the server. Javascript cannot rename a file on the client-side either though it could send a different name with the file being uploaded! What you want to do by the looks of this code is modify the filename after upload but before being saved & logged to database.

In your original code I think you could just change

```
$target_file = 'uploads/documents/'.$filename;
```

to

```
$target_file = 'uploads/documents/'.cleanStr( $filename );
```

however you might try something like this:

```
if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && isset(
    $_GET['id'],
    $_FILES['files']['name']
)) {

    function cleanStr($string) {
       $string = str_replace(' ', '-', $string);
       $string = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $string);
       return preg_replace('/-+/', '-', $string); 
    }
    $count=0;

    # Prepare the sql statement.
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `images` ( `post_id`, `name`, `image` ) VALUES ( ?, ?, ? )";
    $stmt = $db->prepare( $sql );

    # Establish the paths needed - one is the full, absolute path 
    # for saving and the other a relative path for display
    $basedir = __DIR__ . '/uploads/documents/'
    $displaydir = './uploads/documents/';
    
    # Permit these file extensions
    $extns = array( 'png', 'jpeg', 'jpg' ); 
    
    # iterate through all posted images
    foreach( $_FILES['files']['name'] as $i => $name ) {
    
        if( !empty( $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$i] ) ) {
            # we need the `tmp_name` but will modify the $name later
            $name = $_FILES['files']['name'][$i];
            $tmp  = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$i];
            $error= $_FILES['files']['error'][$i];
            
            # find the file extension and file name ( without extension )
            $ext  = strtolower( pathinfo( $name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION ) );
            $name = pathinfo( $name, PATHINFO_FILENAME );
            
            # rudimentary test to see if the file is an image
            list( $width, $height, $type, $attr ) = getimagesize( $tmp );
            
            # Proceed if basic tests are passed.
            if( $error==UPLOAD_ERR_OK && isset( $width, $height, $attr ) && in_array( $ext, $extns )){
                
                # construct the save & display paths using new file name.
                $filename = sprintf('%s-%s.%s', date('Y-m-d-his'), cleanStr( $name ), $ext );
                $savepath=$basedir . $filename;
                $displaypath=$displaydir . $filename;
                
                # move the file and execute sql cmd.
                if( move_uploaded_file( $tmp, $savepath ) ){
                    $stmt->execute(array(
                        $_GET['id'],
                        $filename,
                        $displaypath
                    ));
                    
                    $count++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    exit( header('Location: result.php?id='.$_GET['id'].'&action=UPLOADED&total='.  $count) );
}
```

Comment: thanks a ton. well in my original code i did tried like you said but nothing gets uploaded that way. but anyways you saved me from a big headache really appreciate your kindness.